# Postgresql: How to join several selects of same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I accomplish following query in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT "ItemNumber" AS "Value", 'ItemNumber' AS "Field" FROM item.items JOIN
SELECT "ItemName" AS "Value", 'ItemName' AS "Field" FROM item.items JOIN
SELECT "ItemBarcode" AS "Value", 'ItemBarcode' AS "Field" FROM item.items;
```

The result should be in following format:

```
items: [
{
"Value": "12345677",
"Field": "ItemNumber" 
}, {
"Value": "98776",
"Field": "ItemNumber" 
}, {
"Value": "test77 1",
"Field": "ItemName" 
}, {
"Value": "test77 2",
"Field": "ItemName" 
}, {
"Value": "test77 3",
"Field": "ItemName" 
}, {
"Value": "2342349872934877293847",
"Field": "ItemBarcode" 
}, {
"Value": "9872349877239487923847",
"Field": "ItemBarcode" 
}]
```

Or is there a better way to get that result via SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `union all`?

```
SELECT "ItemNumber" AS "Value", 'ItemNumber' AS "Field" FROM item.items 
UNION ALL
SELECT "ItemName" AS "Value", 'ItemName' AS "Field" FROM item.items 
UNION ALL
SELECT "ItemBarcode" AS "Value", 'ItemBarcode' AS "Field" FROM item.items;
```